# Spline on each column in a category in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How would I draw a spline on columns in each category in Highcharts?

Let's say, I have 5 categories on the x-axis, and each category has 4 columns. Now I want a spline that passes through all the 4 columns in the category (each category should have a separate spline on its corresponding columns)

Is it possible if categories and columns change dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `column` series you can disable `grouping` and set `pointPlacement` to a number value. Than, you can set `x` data values for `spline` series to fit them to the columns:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        startOnTick: true,
        min: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            grouping: false,
            pointWidth: 20
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        pointPlacement: -0.3
    }, {
        data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        pointPlacement: -0.1
    }, {
        data: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        pointPlacement: 0.1
    }, {
        data: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        pointPlacement: 0.3
    }, {
        type: 'spline',
        pointRange: 11,
        data: [
            [-0.3, 1],
            [-0.1, 2],
            [0.1, 3],
            [0.3, 4]
        ]
    }, {
        type: 'spline',
        pointRange: 11,
        data: [
            [0.7, 1],
            [0.9, 2],
            [1.1, 3],
            [1.3, 4]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bdsfty2o/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointWidth

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement

Comment: Thanks for response. Is it possible to add spline series by providing only y coordinates, so how would I set pointPlacement dynamically as my data series changes dynamically (I wont have fixed columns)

Comment: Hi Aksha, I think you could write some algorithm to calculate `x` values. How does your data change? Do you always have 4 columns in one category?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It won't limit to 4 columns, it can reach to 35 sometimes.

Comment: @Aksha, Please create some live demo with an example of data change.

Comment: I did one with sample data. But dint add spline series. [link] (jsfiddle.net/yh31um6f/3/)

Comment: Hi @Aksha, I tried a different approach, using the method `xAxis.toValue` and it seems to work, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w2pa3ugd/